# Why is my subdomain not returning anything?

Tags: web-hosting, apache, virtualhost

I've set up DNS record to test out using virtual hosts prior to moving one of my wordpress installs out of a subdomain. I want to move from mysite.com/blog to blog.mysite.com.

I've tested the DNS resolution for blog.mysite.com with ping and I get a response with the correct public IP address.

```
Pinging blog.mysite.com [x.xxx.xx.xx] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from x.xxx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=52ms TTL=62
Reply from x.xxx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=62
Reply from x.xxx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=54ms TTL=62
Reply from x.xxx.xx.xx: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=62

Ping statistics for x.xxx.xx.xx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 52ms, Maximum = 60ms, Average = 55ms
```

But trying to connect using Chrome I get:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to vhosts.youngbullindustries.com
```

And through telnet:

```
telnet blog.mysite.com 80
Connecting To blog.mysite.com...Could not open connection to
the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

I've tried to tail /apache2/access.log but nothing shows up when I make a request (the level is set to `debug`). I was expecting to see something here but there's nothing at all. What could be going wrong and what should I try next to diagnose the problem?

Edited to add:

The server is running Raspbian, so Debian-style Apache 2.

vhosts file, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/blog` looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.blog.mysite.com
        ServerAlias blog.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

There's also an .htaccess file in /var/www/blog/.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /blog/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your vhost configuration for the blog.mysite.com domain looks like?

It seems like apache isn't configured for the subdomain.

In what environment are you running your server in?

[Update]

And Apache is starting up with this configuration without problems? Anything in the Apache error.log on startup?

There is no direcory-section for the blog directory - maybe adding the directory section helps.

[Update 2]

Are there more files located in the sites-enabled directory?

These files are loaded alphabetically - so maybe there is some directive in another file that stops the rendering of the logfiles?

[Update 3]

Dang - just saw it in your first post ... is the file linked in your sites-enabled directory?
the sites-available directory isn't walked through by apache

**[Update 4 - Chat Summary - Final Disclosure]**

We figured out two problems in the chat.

The first one is the faulty .htaccess file: there was still a blog directory in the RewriteRule line which isn't right when using a subdomain

The second and even more fatal was a failing DNS configuration.

Both failures would've led to a similar error.

Comment: It's running on Raspbian, so Debian-style Apache 2 installation. Edited the question to include the vhost file.

Comment: Nothing that looks relevant in the error log on restart.
`[Wed Apr 30 13:21:23 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 30 13:21:25 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 30 13:21:25 2014] [info] Server built: Feb  8 2014 17:44:20`

I tried adding a directory section for the blog directory and no change.

Comment: once again a update

Comment: Yes, there is: 000-default is also enabled - should I disable that?

Comment: Yes, it's linked. I've disabled 000-default and now error.log shows `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` - looks like progress of a kind. Though that is when navigating to mysite.com, not blog.mysite.com. That still has no response at all.

Comment: Are there any symlinked files within the DocumentRoot?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14235/discussion-between-jamie-bull-and-kkugelmann)